# Concise way to find max/min with potentially nil value

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I have two arrays, max_of_row (which stores the maximum value in each row) and min_of_col (which stores the minimum value in each col).

I initialize these as max_of_row = [] and min_of_col = [].

This is how I'm filling it in right now:

```
  max_rows = []
  min_cols = []
  for i in 0..mat.length-1
    for j in 0..mat[0].length-1
      val = mat[i][j]
      max_rows[i] = [max_rows[i] || val, val].max
      min_cols[j] = [min_cols[j] || val, val].min
    end
  end
```

It looks weird that I'm using: [max_rows[i] || val, val].max.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Before I had:

```
  if max_rows[i].nil? || max_rows[i] < val
    max_rows[i] = val
  end
  if min_rows[j].nil? || min_cols[j] > val
    min_cols[j] = val
  end
```

which (I think) is worse since it's much longer. Am I right that I should try to change these? If so, is there a better looking way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Here's an example of an array:

```
mat =  
  [[2, 5, 10], 
   [3, 4, 7], 
   [6, 10, 9]]
```

**EDIT**

Here are the expected values:

```
max_of_row = [10, 7, 10]
min_of_col = [2, 4, 7]
```

Comment: give us the 2 input arrays

Comment: okay! what's the expected output you want? where it is written above. We have no time to analyze your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max_rows = mat.map(&:max)
# => [10, 7, 10]

min_cols = mat.transpose.map(&:min)
# => [2, 4, 7]
```

Comment: It seems we are on the race, without telling the OP to provide more info giving them answers,with the power of guess. This is not good. We are making the such OP's habit bad.

Comment: Maybe a `compact` call will be a good addition since he said there could be `nil` values.

Comment: @squiguy No. You are misinterpreting that. The OP mentioned `nil` because of the particular algorithm that OP is taking, namely when it is the first element that is recorded as `max_rows[i]` or `min_cols[j]`, there is no previous value against which it should be compared. You need to be more careful before you comment.

Comment: @sawa Oh alright.  I did indeed.